# skip_before_filter based on 'request'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to invoke a skip_before_filter based on the request object.

pseudo code:

```
skip_before_filter :authorize_user, :if => lambda { |controller| controller.request.ip == '127.0.0.1'
```

Is this possible, it seems you only get :only/:except with skip_filter's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
skip_before_filter :authorize_user, :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  What version of Rails did this work on?  3.2.12 [doesn't document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.12/action_controller_overview.html#filters) this

Comment: Works for me. Ruby 2.0 syntax: `:if ->{ request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'}`